# Sorting submeshes/VBO

Tags: c++, sorting, opengl, vbo

I have a level I need to render. It is broken into hundreds of submeshes with information on which submesh can see which submesh. Each level has a pool of textures that all of those submeshes can reference. All submeshes have vertices that are sorted by texture. Here is an example.

Submesh 1

Index[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 7, 8, 10...] Texture 1

Index[12, 15, 16, 12, 13, 19] Texture 2

When there are 1000 submeshes and 20 textures possible, the amount of texture swapping gets ridiculous even factoring in visibility.

I have all of my submeshes sequentially in a VBO. I have been trying to figure out the best way to go about optimizing rendering and eliminate all unnecissary texture swaps. If I just sort the VBO, I lose the submesh connections and the visibility data becomes useless. Or is there a better way to do that?

Or should i create an index list every frame based on visibility or is that too slow?

Edit: Here is a breakdown of my current setup.

VBO with all of the vertices in order running from submesh 1 texture 1, submesh 1 texture 2, all the way to submesh n, texture n.

I have an IBO which is just all of the indices to all of the meshes, in the same relative order.

When I render, I consult the submesh and have an starting index and count which are the start index in the IBO for that submesh and texture and then the count which is the number that have that texture.

This is essentially why I am doing so much swapping which is really slowing things down.

Comment: Is there a possibility of merging a few of these textures in to a larger one?

Comment: @Aleks It's possible. I'd rather not use a texture atlas though.

Comment: What do you mean by "texture swapping"? You should at least have 32 texture units to play with.

Comment: @Grimmy Every time I get to a new texture in a submesh, I use glBindTexture to bind the next texture.

Comment: Why does sorting VBO renders you visibility data useless. Why they need to be sequential in your vbo?

Comment: I would traverse visibility data, generate a list of what to render and then short that list by render states. At the end the whole vbo is just one big array that is accessed sequential (regarding a submesh) you wont make many cache misses here.

Comment: @Trax My submeshes keep track of a starting point in the VBO, the starting index. If I was to sort it, I would lose the ability to access the point by index. I guess I could use a pointer and it would move with the sort?

Comment: You don't need to change the vbo, it is already sorted for your needs. With the information given I would create some sort of display list for each texture which points to which submeshes we need to render this frame for that texture. Then loop all textures, check the renderer list and render all submeshes in that render list. Build the render list according to the visibility information. If this is not clear enough I will try to make an answer with some drawing to make this idea clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> VBO with all of the vertices in order running from submesh 1 texture 1, submesh 1 texture 2, all the way to submesh n, texture n.

There's your problem. A "submesh" should be a *single rendering call*, not *multiple* rendering calls. Each "submesh" should be the equivalent of your "submesh X, texture Y" pairs. A particular submesh uses a particular set of `glVertexAttribPointer` calls, `glBindTexture` calls, and a single `glDrawElements` call to render.

Each submesh in this scheme uses a *specific* texture. Therefore, you can sort your draw order by which textures they use. So all submeshes that use texture 1 can be rendered at the same time, with just one `glBindTexture` call between them.

For best performance, since all of your "submeshes" use the same buffers (and therefore, it's a good change that they all use the same vertex format), you should also try to [use `glDrawElementsBaseVertex`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glDrawElementsBaseVertex) to render a particular "submesh", rather than making separate `glVertexAttribPointer` calls for each submesh.

The idea there is to make your VBO effectively one long array, with all of every submesh's vertices in the same array. Each submesh stores a base offset to its index data, a count of vertices to render, and a base vertex offset, which represents where which index that submesh's data starts in the big array.

At the start of rendering all submeshes, you make *one* set of `glVertexAttribPointer` calls. And then it's just `glBindTexture` and `glDrawElementsBaseVertex` from then on. You don't call `glVertexAttribPointer` ever for each submesh. You use the BaseVertex to define where each submesh's data comes from in the VBO.

Answer (score 1):

After your edit:

**You need a mid step, which would short meshes to render based on texture id. You need to make a drawing call (`glDrawElements`), per submesh.** With this in mind you can do the following:

Basically you do the same, but instead of rendering stuff, store that mesh into a display list for the texture it needs.

Create an object called display list, which holds an array of submesheses (*pointers*) to be rendered. Create an array of such objects, 1 per texture id you have.

In your algorithm, before rendering stuff, fill the above structure and don't render anything yet.

When you are done resolving what is visible and needs rendering, traverse the the array of display lists (0....num_textures) and render the submeshses for that texture. **HINT**: In this step you can find adjacent submeshes and just perform one call to `glDrawElements`.

Optimized the above idea.

This is easy to implement and will minimize texture state changes.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you'll have a index buffer as well, you pass into `glDrawElements`. I suggest rearranging the contents in the index buffer. Or, if you don't want to modify the data, call glDrawElements for each submesh separately with the right offset and vertex count and sort the meshes by texture.

Comment: Unless he is drawing everything he needs to call glDrawElements several times. Probably one for each mesh or find the contiguous ones and fire just one glDrawElements with a larger length.

Comment: datenwolf, if I am rearranging the contents in the index buffer, will I need a pointer to the correct position in the index? The way I do it now is that I have my big VBO and my IBO. Each mesh has an index into the VBO and a number of vertices matching that texture. So if I wanted to render all of texture3 in submesh 8, I would use glDrawElements and start at the stored index. How could I make it more flexible so that when I sort my IBO I can still have the correct location? Should I build my IBO more intelligently and maybe sort it as I go keeping the sorted offset?